# IBM WAS 8.5.5 Admin Console is slow and blank page appears after saving changes

Tags: performance, websphere

I am using IBM WebSphere Application Server V 8.5.5 on Windows 7 for my custom Java EE application. Of late, the Admin Console has been behaving little weird. After I complete my deployment or make any configuration changes in the Admin console, it takes too  long to respond or rather it gives a blank page.

I have been searching the forums but no proper solution so far. I had deleted and recreated the Profile but no luck.

Has anyone faced a similar scenario? Is there a way to resolve this?

[UPDATE on 25Aug2015] Turning off the Antivirus, resolved the issue.

Comment: I've seen increasing the max heap size on the dmgr (ND) or appserver (other editions) help with extremely slow responsiveness of the console.

Comment: @covener, thanks. I had already set the max heap size to a considerable amount (6GB). Will it still not suffice?

Comment: I've never seen it require excessive, just marginally more then the default.

Comment: Hi, we suspected that the slowness could be because of Antivirus in the OS. We turned off the antivirus and it was working fine. Hope it may be useful for someone who faces this issue later.

Comment: @itsraghz describe it in the answer, rather than update to the question.

Comment: @Gas I did both in the same order.